# Only one use of each socket address

Tags: port, sharpsvn

Having problems with ports on a server. Users have to begun experience getting the exception "Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted." It seems to be at random times and only one user at a time have reported the problem.

(The server the in question is using subversion/sharpSVN if it is of any help.)

After looking through solutions online I tested increasing the dynamic port range to almost the double without any noticeable change in user problems.

I'm very new to anything networking, is it something obvious I am missing to check?
Otherwise, is there some simple way to set up logging on the server for what ports are being used during the day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it seemed as the server was the problem, it was actually a client side problem with users ports getting used up due to newly introduced parallelization. (Solution was more caching and combined calls.)